# C++ Heap memory in array assignment only messing up for the first array and not the second

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, heap-memory

I have an assignment to create two functions in an array class named insert and print. Insert should add elements to the end of the array and when I run the code, I get output that looks fine for the second array but the first array gives strange output. I don't really know where to go from here and any pointers help
[image: Image of my output]

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Array //The array class
{
private:
     //Data members capacity, size, and arr (a pointer that points to the first element of the array in the heap).
     int capacity{};
     int size{};
     int* arr{};
public:
     Array(int capacity);//parameter
     Array();//default
     ~Array();//destructor
     void insert(int num);
     void print() const ;

};
void Array::insert(int num) 
{
     {
          if (size == 0)
          {
               arr[0] = num;
               size++;
               return;
          }
          int index = 0;
          while (num > arr[index] && index < size)
          {
               index++;
          }
          arr[index] = num;
          size++;
     }
}

void Array::print() const
{`enter code here`

     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
     {
          cout << *(arr+i)<<" ";
     }

     
     delete[]arr;
}


Array::Array()
{
     return;
}

//Destructor to clean up 
Array::~Array()
{
     return;
}

//Parameter constructor
Array::Array(int cap)
     :capacity(cap)
{
     arr = new int[capacity];
     size = 0;

}

int main()
{

          // Creation of an array with a capacity of 10
          Array array1(10);
          array1.insert(5);
          array1.insert(3);
          array1.insert(2);
          cout << "Array 1: " << endl;
          array1.print();
          cout << endl; 
          // Creation of another array    
          Array array2(20);
          for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
          {
               array2.insert(i + 10);
          }
          cout << "Array 2: " << endl;
          array2.print();
          cout << endl;
          return 0;

}
```

Comment: If your array has `size` elements, what is the index of its end?

Comment: I'm sorry to say, there so many mistakes in the code shown, it is very hard to know where to start. Note that in `Array::Array()` you don't create an array. In `insert` you never grow the array when size reaches capacity. The destructor is empty, while it should be deleting the array. Your print function deletes the array. All of which are critical errors. Start by being sure you understand what `new[]` and `delete[]` do, and what a constructor and destructor is used for.

Comment: Thank you I was able to get out some errors by moving the delete to the destructor, initializing the allocated array, and moving the delete array out of the print function. I am now getting the Array1 ouput of 2 0 0 which is a step in the right direction since i'm no longer getting junk values

Comment: Thank you for your help, I was able to get the numbers to print out correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not initialize the allocated array in

```
arr = new int[capacity];
```

so its content is garbage.

Then in your `insert()` you attempt to insert the element in ascending order, but you do NOT move existing elements up; you simply overwrite them.

Your `print` the prints that garbage.

The second test case works because your elements are already ordered, so no move is needed.

Comment: I edited the mentioned line and replaced it with      arr = {new int[capacity] {}}; 
The first array now prints out 2 0 0, A new error is progress :) Thank you for catching that

Comment: Thank you for your help, I was able to get the numbers to print out correctly

Comment: @AngelArmendariz You are welcome. If you feel that I've answered your question, you may accept it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer